# What is the probability of pulling exactly 2 blue marbles when pulling 7 marbles from a bag of 21 marbles containing 3 blue and 18 red marbles

Tags: probability

Hi I've just go no idea about how I should go about getting the correct answer to this one. I already created a small program that should give me a somewhat OK indication of what the probability would be, but obviously I have to do it with math and not "brute force"-programming.

pseudocode for that python script looks like this:

```
function checkExactlyTwo():
 array = []
 for i in range(21):
   if(i<3): 
     array.append("B")
   else:
     array.append("R")
 array.shuffle()
 picked = array[-7:]
 if(picked.count("B")==2)
   return True
 else 
   return False

trues=0
for(y in range(1000000000)):
  trues+=1
  print(trues/y)
```

now this seems to establish itself around 0.22, but I have to idea about how to get to that calculating the probability on paper. If I take the probability by multiplying 3/21 * 2/20 * 18/19 *17/18... and so on it leads to around 0.01 and I guess I'd have to multiply it by all the possible combinations having two blue to get to the correct answer, but I have no idea about what to do to find the exact number of possible combinations containing two blue.

Comment: [Hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) ( $N=21, K=3, n=7, k=2$)

Comment: Thank you, that seems right!

Comment: I assume you're talking about pulling the marbles without replacement, but that's probably something you should make express in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Total number of ways to choose $7$ out of $21$ marbles: $21 \choose 7$. Number of ways to pick $2$ out of $3$ blue marbles and $5$ out of $18$ red marbles: ${3 \choose 2}{18 \choose 5}.$ Answer:
$$
\frac{{3 \choose 2}{18 \choose 5}}{{21 \choose 7}}.
$$